# Add regex to allow only letters, disallow certain character

Tags: php, forms, validation

how to insert regex to allow only letters and whitespace on Name field and disallow "-" dash only entry on Phone field? here is the code. I believe i have to insert an elseif condition but i'm having hard time constructing the whole thing.

```
// loop through each of our form fields
    foreach ($fdata as $field => $value) {


        // Now switch functionality based on field name
        switch ($field) {

            // name
            case 'name':
                if (empty($value)) {
                    array_push($errors, parseMessage($translations->form->error->required->$lang, array($field)));
                }
                break;

            // email
            case 'email':
                if (empty($value)) {
                    array_push($errors, parseMessage($translations->form->error->required->$lang, array($field)));
                } elseif (!filter_var($value, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
                    array_push($errors, $translations->form->error->email->$lang);
                }
                break;

            // phone number
            case 'phone':
                if (!empty($value) && !is_numeric($value)) {
                    array_push($errors, parseMessage($translations->form->error->numeric->$lang, array($field)));
                }
                break;

            // message
            case 'honey':
                if (!empty($value)) {
                    array_push($errors, $translations->form->error->honeypot->$lang);
                }
                break;

        }
    }
```

Comment: you'd need a regex too

Comment: It is not JavaScript you are showing here.

Comment: sorry forgot to replace the tag

Comment: @TheDon Feel free to do so. You can still [edit] it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless I've misunderstood the question, this is all you need:

```
switch ($field) {
    case 'name':
       # Check if the name is empty.
       if (empty($value)) {...}

       # If not, check if the name consists of letters and spaces.
       else if (preg_match("/^[a-z ]+$/i")) {...}

       break;

    case 'phone':
       # Check if the phone is empty.
       if (empty($value)) {...}

       # If not, check if the phone does not contain a hyphen.
       else if (preg_match("/^[^-]+$/")) {...}

       break;
}
```